# AEM Multifield - Modifying values in multifield values

Tags: java, aem, sling, aem-6, sling-models

Multifield issue

NotificationAlert.java

```
@Model(adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class,
        Resource.class}, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class NotificationAlerts {

 @Inject
    @Via("resource")
    @Default(values = CommonConstants.EMPTY)
    @Named("notificationItems")
    private List<ListingModel> notificationItems;

    public List<ListingModel> getNotificationItems() {
        return notificationItems;
    }

    public void setNotificationItems(List<ListingModel> notificationItems) {
        this.notificationItems = notificationItems;
    }

@PostConstruct
    private void initModel() {
       for(ListingModel model : notificationItems)
       {
         String createTime = model.getCreateTime();
         String formattedTime = changeDateFormat(createTime); 
//When I debugged I got the formattedTime correctly
//But not setting below
         model.setCreateTime(formattedTime); 
       }
    }

String changeDateFormat(String dateValue)
{
//definiton
}
}
```

And the ListingModel.java Interface

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public interface ListingModel {

@Inject
    String getNotificationLogo();
    
    @Inject
    String getCreateTime();

    public void setCreateTime(String value);
    
    @Inject
    boolean isActive();

}
```

I have tried declaring a setter function in the interface and try calling it in
@PostConstruct.

But it is not changing

I want to format the createTime using changeDateFormat(String value)

Or can I call the changeDateFormat() in sightly ?

How do I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I want to know how to modify the createTime value as edited in @PostConstruct. The setter is not setting anything.

Also, there is a setter method in the interface

Comment: Please show us the code you tried to run in place of the `//Tried changing the createTime here` comment.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what it is you’re asking. The title refers to the “Interface Setter” but the question body seems to be about the `@PostConstruct` method not being run.

Comment: I have corrected and made it more clear. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a sling model from an interface as opposed to a class, sling only implements getters annotated with `@Inject`. Anything else is stubbed out with dummy no-op implementations, which is why the setter doesn’t do anything.

If you want the setter to work, make `ListingModel` a class instead of an interface and inject fields instead of methods.

Then, you can add your own getters and setters to the `ListingModel` and they can modify the field, if desired:

```java
@Model(
    adaptables = Resource.class,
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
public class ListingModel {
    @Inject
    private String notificationLogo;
    
    @Inject
    private String createTime;
    
    @Inject
    private boolean active;

    public String getNotificationLogo() {
        return notificationLogo;
    }

    public String getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public String isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(String value) {
        this.createTime = value;
    }
}
```

If the logic to format the create time isn’t dependent on anything in `NotificationAlerts`, you could even maybe do the formatting on the fly in the `getCreateTime` method, thus removing the need to have a setter at all or a `@PostConstruct` method on `NotificationAlerts`.

Comment: From HTL, using data-sly-use can I invoke the changeDateFormat(String date) with arguments passed from HTL ?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to call methods other than getters from HTL.